# Before image upload, sort them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

all, I have problem with sortable.

I temporarily save image with ajax and show them without image upload, now i want to sort that picture and on button to save "sort" version.

This HTML li's are full with some images example : `<li><img src="" /></li>`

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
</script>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @juvian Saving in database sort version

Comment: What language are you using for your backend?

Comment: @BryceSiedschlaw is that matter?

Comment: Well, you need to have in your database something like index and send the image sorted indexes, then you show them according to that index

Comment: @juvian can you tell me how, I will appreciate that.

Comment: You already have the images stored in database but want to change the order they display? Or you want to add the images to database in the order you specified?

Comment: @juvian I have temporarily folder for(only viewing images and sort them before saving in another folder). I save in database random name of every image with separated by commas.
Now i want to somehow before saving to change "order" of names and than save it. I hope you understand this

Comment: Well, you need to associate those random image names with each image in the client. Not sure how are you saving those, but you need to have those names in the client too. Then you can check the new order and send the new comma separated name list

Comment: @juvian I did it with index, put datakeywords to every ul li, and after sort, with each loop fix the thing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you drop a sortable item you will need to update it's index in data.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function( e, ui ) {
        console.log( $( ui.item ).index() );  
    }
});
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/ for events that are triggered

Comment: this is not my answer, but thanks

Comment: @NebojsaSapic This is the answer, if you can invoke ajax request to the server and save that index (in this case index == order)